# How to build a function in R that splits variables into intervals and calculate mean, sd and a count for the intervals

Tags: r, function

I try to split a Age variable into intervals, calculate mean, sd and a count for the intervals then save the outputs for every interval in a vector and then combine these vectors to a data frame where for every interval I can simply take the values.

I've done this:

```
intervals <- function(g){
  i1 <- c()
  i2 <- c()
  i3 <- c()
  i4 <- c()
  i5 <- c()
  if(g <= 30){
    i1 <- c(mean(g), sd(g))
    df <- cbind(i1)
  }else if(g > 30 & g <= 40){
      i2 <- c(mean(g), sd(g))
      df <- cbind(i2)
  }else if(g > 40 & g <= 50){
      i3 <- c(mean(g), sd(g))
      df <- cbind(i3)
  }else if(i >50 & i <= 60){
      i4 <- c(mean(g), sd(g))
      df <- cbind(i4)
  }else if(g > 60){
      i5 <- c(mean(g), sd(g))
      df <- cbind(i5)
  }else{
 } 
return(df)
}
```

This is what I get from my code:

```
           i3
[1,] 45.22727
[2,] 13.11818
```

I havent even tried to include the count because I had no chance to workout a solution.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a function, but it achieves what you want:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(
  age = runif(100, min = 10, max = 100)
)


# trying to first define the categories and then calculate the descriptive statistics
# edit: I used @thelatemail suggestion from the comments to simplify the code
df %>%
  group_by(category = cut(age, c(0,30,40,50,60,Inf), labels=paste0("i",1:5))) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(age),
    sd = sd(age),
    count = n()
  )
```

Comment: Alternatively, drop all the `case_when` and `mutate` and use `cut` like `group_by(category = cut(age, c(0,30,40,50,60,Inf), labels=paste0("i",1:5)))`

Comment: That's a useful hint. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! When I apply your code to my data which is a column of a data frame. I get as it is with my code only the values for the total sample not by groups. ```mean sd 45.22727 13.11818``` Also there seems to be a problem with the count function. ```Error: n() should only be called in a data context```

Comment: I didnt work because plyr somehow blocked dplyr. After uninstalling it, your solution works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
intervals <- function(ages, 
                      interval_limits=c(0, 30, 40, 50, 60, Inf),
                      labels = NULL) {
    as.data.frame(lapply(split(ages, 
                               cut(ages, interval_limits)), 
                         function(vec) c(mean = mean(vec),
                                         sd = sd(vec),
                                         count = length(vec))))
}
```

try it using:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  age = runif(100, min = 10, max = 100)
)
intervals(df$age)

# output:
        X.0.30.  X.30.40.  X.40.50.  X.50.60. X.60.Inf.
mean  21.094326 35.094549 44.625106 54.240979 79.692913
sd     5.930636  3.175697  2.913968  2.613085  9.707679
count 17.000000 10.000000 16.000000 12.000000 45.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately i get this error: ```Error in names(res) <- labels : 
  'names' attribute [44] must be the same length as the vector [5]```

Comment: @Justus Blachke fixed - it needed `levels(categories)`. In addition I reformat it using regex.

Comment: @Justus Blaschke in R, the automatically generated categories have the form `(30,40]` - but the regex catches the numbers and makes out of this: `30<=40`. And it can catch also `+Inf`, `-Inf`, `Inf` and removes empty space before ` Inf` which occurs when giving `+Inf`.

Comment: It works perfectly also with my data! Thank you! I'll now try to understand what you did :D